# What is the difference between http post and Redirect in CakePHP

Tags: http, cakephp, post

What is the difference between

```
$HttpSocket->post('http://localhost:8090/example/samplecontroller/add', $data);
```

and

```
$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'samplecontroller','action' => 'add', $data));
```

Both post the data ,whereas first method is not working for me.
I used

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http'); and
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```

How to make it work? Or The second method is also HTTPpost?

> **Edited**

```
 public function httppost() {
    App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    $HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $data = array('name' => 'test', 'type' => 'user');
    $response = $HttpSocket->post('http://localhost:8090/catv/airtime_masters/httpget', $data);
    return $response;
}

 public function httpget() {
    debug($this->request->data);
    exit;
}
```

when i run httpget() i get `array()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think they both POST the data, Im pretty sure redirect will send the data as GET method.. or as url vars e.g(?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2).

They are quite different. redirect is used when you want the user to sent to another page. The HTTPSocket->Post method is used when you want to post some data to a URL and do something with the response e.g:

```
$response = $HttpSocket->post('http://localhost:8090/example/samplecontroller/add', $data);
/** do something with $response data here **/
```

Comment: Yes i tried this,But how to know it is posted or not? because when i try to get url data from "http://localhost:8090/example/samplecontroller/add" it is returning null.

Comment: in your `samplecontroller/add` action add `debug($this->request->data);exit;`
If an array of the posted data is returned then you know you have hit it. the return data will be in the `$response` var if you are using my example.

Comment: It still returning null :( check my full code edited.

Comment: And you can access `add()` from the browser fine? when POSTing data try encoding as json e.g `$response = $HttpSocket->post('http://localhost:8090/catv/airtime_masters/httpget', json_encode($data));` Cakes Request handler will automatically decode json strings into the request objects data property

Comment: yea actually i want json encoded data only.but before that i need posted data.and i am unable to get it ..

Comment: Post is the http request method . Not the data type.